# Multiply n 10 times in java (Beginner)

Tags: java, math

I just started to learn Java with the Standford course. As you may know every other chapter teaches you how to create program to solve a problem. I always tend to practice a little bit more by creating new problems based on what we get on the course.
As im learning the ***for*** statement I tried to create a program that multiplies n 10 times. So it would be n * n * n... and so on...
And it works, but i was wondering if there was a simpler way to solve this problem.
Here is my code.

```
/*This program multiplies an n number 10 times.
* 
*/

import acm.program.ConsoleProgram;

public class LiftOff extends ConsoleProgram {

    public void init() {
        setSize(height,width);
    }

    private static final int height = 600;
    private static final int width = 600;

    public void run () {
        println ("This program multiplies a number 10 times");
        double x= readInt("Number: ");

        double stop = x * x * x * x * x * x * x * x * x * x * x;

        for (double x1 = x ; x1 <= stop; x1*= x) {
            println (x1);
        }

        println("Done");
    }
}
```

I used doubles because int would go negative. I tried to make double stop = xE+10 but it would not work. Any solutions other than this one base on what I've learned so far. Take into account this uses the acm library.

Thanks.

Comment: You could post this at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). *Code Review is a question and answer site for sharing code from projects you are working on
for peer review.*

Comment: Consider using `long` or `BigInteger` if the input is large enough.

Comment: Thats equivalent to raising a number to the 10th power, and there's a method built into java.lang.Math to do just that (its a common operation for some problem domains): Math.pow(number, 10);

Comment: @Thinkingcap From the question he states explicitly that he's trying to learn the basics of Java (for loops).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a loop from `1` to `9` and each time multiply the initial value of `x` by itself.

```
double x= readInt("Number: ");
double result = x;

for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
    result *= x;
```

Comment: You are using x instead of i as a variable. "int i=1" is the correct syntax

Comment: yeah thanks for pointing out. victim of speed :P. I corrected it

Answer (score 0):

```
    double number = 5;  //readDouble("Number: ");
    double total = number; // == number*1
    for ( int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        total = total * number;
    System.out.println(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are computing the result twice (first time with stop). How would you do if you wanted to compute n^1000 ? There's much simpler :

```
int pow = 10;
int n   = 3;
int res = 1;
for (int i=0 ; i<pow ; i++)
   res *= n;
```

It may be a bit advanced for a beginner, but you might be interested to know that there are much faster ways to compute a^b. Take a look at [fast exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).